# Defining a normal subgroup to be maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I just want to clear up something from Question 2. from the following my professor made:

[image]

For Question 2., if $|G|=p$ and $N$ is maximal, does that mean $|N|\neq p$ since there is no subgroup $H$ of $G$ (including $G$ itself) such that $N\leq H\leq G$?

Comment: Yes, from the definition provided, a maximal subgroup must be a *proper* subgroup, which is to say, it cannot equal the whole group. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes! And it is my bad, because I did not see the condition $H\neq G$.